# Getting image mime type: pathinfo vs image_type_to_mime_type

Tags: php

I'm trying to get image mime type in php. I've two options, 1st and 2nd, The 1st one requires a longer code check all mime types eg; jpg, png and gif etc. It uses multipel conditions but it works well.

The 2nd code is just a line but it also works well. But I don't know which one is faster and takes less memory, any idea?

**1st option:**

```
$filedetails = pathinfo($image);
if($filedetails['extension'] == 'jpe' || $filedetails['extension'] == 'jpg' || $filedetails['extension'] == 'jpeg') {
$mime = 'image/jpeg';
} elseif($filedetails['extension'] == 'png') { ... so on
```

**2nd Option:**

```
$mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($image));
```

Comment: The second is more accurate as its not relying on the extension but instead the file format ... you could have a `png` named `imreallyapng.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

These are completely different functions and serve completely different purpose.

**pathinfo** gets information about a file path, it doesn't actually open the file and won't check contents of the file. I can easily create .mp3 file and change file extension to .jpg. File extension is **not** same as mime type - it is just the part of a file path.

**exif_imagetype** on the other hand does open the file and tries to quess file type based on file contents.

So basically pathinfo will be faster since it actually won't open the file but exif_imagetype will give you more reliable results because file extensions can be faked.

It is also worth noting that exif_imagetype relies on the exif extension - recognized types can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php). More generic solution would be to use [FileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php). Following requires php 5.3.x or newer.

```
$path = 'nuclear_dinosaur_mushroom.png';
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = $finfo->file($path);
if (preg_match('/^image\/.+/i', $mime)) {
    //Should be image file
}
```